# What is the flow of statement after thread.start() gets called in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

what statement gets execution after thread.start(). Main thread's statement or child thread's statement.

Threads usually run in parallel but in this case, always main thread's statement has priority over child's. what is the actual reason or flow?

```
public class Test extends Thread { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        ChildThread ct = new ChildThread(); 
        ct.start();
        System.out.println("main"); 
    } 
} 
class ChildThread extends Thread{ 
    @Override public void run() {       
        System.out.println("Child thread"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: o/p :
Main
Child thread

Comment: It is undeterministic. Either it is `main -- Child thread` or `Child thread -- main` (-- represents a new line. It depends on when ChildThread runs, and in your case there is not flow control so it is undeterministic.

Comment: Why do you think it has priority? Just because it prints "main" first? The child thread needs to initialize and start while the main thread is already running, of course it can finish its task earlier. But it doesn't has a higher prio than "child".

Comment: so the flow would be parent create and call child thread and both start their statements parallelly in case of main its very next (print) gets called and in case of threads its run function gets executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to Thread::start means the thread is put in the queue to processors. After that call, the parent and child thread runs in parallel. The parent thread immediately executes *System.out.println("main");* The child thread waits for a free processor to execute (well, we can assume there is a always a free processor available). Then it does some system work: mark the processor as occupied, change the state of the thread as running, then pass the control to the run() method, and only then *System.out.println("Child thread");* will be executed.

Answer (score 6):

There is no certain answer what statement gets execution after thread.start(), but in the most cases it will be the main thread, because when you start the new thread your OS needs to initialize this thread, while main thread is already on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

This is because it takes some time for the `JVM` to call `ct.run()` after you call `ct.start()` as making the new `Thread` run is a heavy operation. The lag gives enough time to print "main".

However if you try to print both in loops you'll see that there is no priority given to the main `Thread`.